# Unity3d web player fails to load textures

Tags: unity, web

I'm having a problem with Unity3d Web Player. I have developed a project and succesfully deployed it in a web app. It works with absolutely no problem on my PC.

This app is to be installed on two identical machines. I have installed them in both and it only works properly in one. The issue I have is on a computer it fails to properly load the models and textures, so the game runs but instead of the models I can only see black rectangles on a blue background. It has the same problem with all browsers and I get no errors either by the player or by JavaScript.

The only difference between these computers is that one that has the problem is running on Windows 8.1 and the other one on Windows 8 only. Could this be the cause of the issue?

It works fine on my computer with Windows 8.1. However both of the other computers have specs that are significantly lower than mine.

I have already searched everywhere and it seems that it has to do with the individual games, however I think it may have to do with the computer itself because it runs properly in the other two.

The specs on the computes I'm installing the app on are as follows: Intel Celeron 1.40 GHz, 2GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful

I forgot to mention, I'm running Unity Web player 4.3.5 and the version on the other two computers is 4.5.0